# Link is not working after parsing it from string

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I've got some html code in my View. For example:

```
        <b>Some text</b>
        <p style="color:#337ab7">
            Some other text
            <a href="~/Content/files/my file_form.pdf" style="font-size:smaller; text-decoration:underline" target="_blank">SEE CONTENT</a>
        </p>
```

As You can see, the code contains the link to some .pdf.  It works fine. Instead of this I want to be able read the html from the string I provide via the class:

```
 public static class ResourceParser
    {
        public static string GetTextFromResource(string keyValue)
        {
            var path = "MyProject.MyRepository.App_GlobalResources.pl";

            var res_manager = new ResourceManager(path, typeof(pl).Assembly);

            return res_manager.GetString(keyValue);
        }
    }
```

So instead of this html code in my View I'd want to have something like:

```
@Html.Raw(ResourceParser.GetTextFromResource("textAfterAllDataOnEmployeeEditPage"))
```

to load my html from resources. 
The problem is that when I use it like this, the link does not work and the site shows an 404 error.

Comment: what is the link url (that shows 404)? it should guide you that what you are doing wrong

Comment: @Ashkan Mobayen Khiabani  So... Yeah, it kind of helps but I still don't know how to fix it. The url that's **working** : http://localhost:63656/Content/files/my%file_form.pdf   and the link I'm trying to send via my method: http://localhost:63656/Employee/~/Content/files/my file_form.pdf    Why the Employee part is there? I mean, It's my view but it wasn't in the link before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use root-relative links in your HTML string, for example you need to replace:

```
href="~/Content/etc.pdf"
```

With

```
href="/Content/etc.pdf"
```

In your specific case, this will solve the problem. The special character `~` in your view gets parsed into the full path, it's not a feature of HTML.

Comment: Bonus question. Is there any way to make somethig like:  <a href="@Url.Action("Index","Documents")" style="color:#00B0F0;">Documents List</a>.   work? I know that @Url.Action is a part of razor syntax and I'd like to know if there is any way to pass it as a string and the view would know how to use it     Edit: yeah, yeah, I pressed enter too soon ;)

Comment: I think the comment ate your bonus question :)

Comment: Edited the comment ;)

Comment: @Fenton When I was reading your answer, at the first example I was thinking - what you've changed? `2` at the end of `pdf2`, where do you get that? Then I read the last part and saw the `~`, it was a typo or something.

Comment: @SeM - the UK keyboard has `"` as `SHIFT` + `2`... it was meant to be a closing quote. Oops! :)